# how can i edit services.yaml after overriding FOUserBundle

Tags: symfony-4.2

- I integrated FOSUserBundle to my project in Symfony 4, everything is ok.

  - My goal : add 2 attributes in user.php (name and firstname).
    My steps:

    1. i added these 2 attributes in User.php (src Entity User.php) -- ok
    2. i move to my terminal to genrate the migration -- ok
    3. i created new folder Form (src Form) and new file inside RegistrationFormTYpe.php (see background)
    4. i edited services.yaml (see background)
    5. i edited fos_user.yaml in (config fos_user.yaml)..maybe it's the wrong file..cause config.yaml doesn't exist in symfony 3 (see background)
    6. see console error in background...
       Does anyone have a solution ? must i give up to integrate fosuser in symfony 4 ?

//src\Form;

```php
    namespace src\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseRegistrationFormType;

    class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
            ->add('name',TextType::class,array(
                'label' => 'Nom',
                'required' => TRUE,
                'attr' =>array(
                    'class='=>'form-group form-control'
                )
            ))
            ->add('firstname',TextType::class,array(
                'label' => 'Prénom',
                'required' => TRUE,
                'attr' =>array(
                    'class='=>'form-group form-control'
                )
            ))


            ;

        }

        public function getParent(){
            return BaseRegistrationFormType::class;
        }

        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'app_user_registration';
        }
    }
```

// config\services.yaml

```
    # This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
    # Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

    # Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
    parameters:
        locale: 'fr'

    services:

        app.form.registration:
            class: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
            tags:
                - { name: form.type }    
                - { firstname: form.type }        

        # default configuration for services in *this* file
        _defaults:
            autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
            autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

        # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
        # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
        App\:
            resource: '../src/*'
            exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,EventListener,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

        # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
        # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
        App\Controller\:
            resource: '../src/Controller'
            tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

// config\fos_user.yaml

```
    fos_user:
        db_driver: orm
        user_class: App\Entity\User
        firewall_name: main
        service:
            mailer: fos_user.mailer.noop
        from_email:
            address: "sebvrg@gmail.com"
            sender_name: "sebvrg@gmail.com"
        registration: 
            form:
                type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
```

// output in console :

```
    In FileLoader.php line 166:

      A "tags" entry is missing a "name" key for service "app.form.registration" in C:\Users\sebvr\Desktop\Projets\SELT\selt\config/services.yaml in C:\Users\sebvr\Deskt
      op\Projets\SELT\selt\config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "C:\Users\sebvr\Desktop\Projets\SELT\selt\config/services.yaml").


    In YamlFileLoader.php line 489:

      A "tags" entry is missing a "name" key for service "app.form.registration" in C:\Users\sebvr\Desktop\Projets\SELT\selt\config/services.yaml.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you extend your User entity aswell?

```php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $firstname;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
    }
}
```

And did you register the form in app/config/config.yml?

```
fos_user:
    registration:
        form:
            type: AppBundle\Form\RegistrationFormType
```

Also your tag says Symfony 4.2 but you are using the structure of symfony 3 (AppBundle) instead of (App)